# Changing User Agent to IE6 or lower for curl call

Tags: php, curl, header, user-agent

i am trying to scrap a page using curl however if a user visit this page with browsers higher then IE6 most of the page text is being populated with javascript thus returning empty elements.

my idea was in my curl call to either change user agent to IE6 or if possible to turn JS off. i know curl is server side but there should be a way to act as if JS is off or browser is IE6

the way i have my user agent now is:

`$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13";`

I wasn't the one who set it up. i downloaded it somewhere. any idea how can i do the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing that line to this:

```
$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: What were your results? Did it show up with the javascript still inserting in? Did it error out? What happened? Details.

Comment: alext i checked again to see if i am blind.. and i am blind. it worked but i was sure it didnt

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$opts = array("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $opts );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You've only inserted my text above to an array how would that solve anything ?